# Angular 2 Updating Component After Form Submit With New Data From Response

Tags: angular

**Background**

On page load I am making a http get call to obtain some data.

There is a form on the page which submits new data to the APi. The response does not hold the new updated data but the data exist in the database after the form is submitted.

I need to access the data by making a second api call after the form is submitted.

**Question**

After the form is submitted, how do I make the initial API call again to retrieve current data and then update my view component with it?

**Code**

On page load I call this function inside

*Initial call to retrieve data*

```
ngOnInit() { this.getPaymentMethods() }
```

*Function definition*

```
private getPaymentMethods() {
            let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
            params.set('api_key', this.apiKeyData);
            params.set('email', this.auth.user.email);
            return this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_ALL_PAYMENT_METHODS,
                { search: params })
                .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe((res) => {
                    localStorage.setItem('payment_profiles', JSON.stringify(res.payment_profiles));
                });
        }
```

Handling Response From Initial Call

*Parsing the data object response*

```
this.PaymentMethodKeys = Object.keys(this.pMethodsData);
```

*Inside the view I display the data like this*

```
<div *ngFor="let key of PaymentMethodKeys">
{{pMethodsData[key].card_no}}
{{pMethodsData[key].payment_profile_id}}
</div>
```

This is the form that is submitted to add new data to database

```
    saveCreditCard(model: Payment, isValid: boolean) {
            let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
            params.set('api_key', this.apiKeyData);
            params.set('email', model.email);

   params.set('u_address', model.street_address);
            params.set('u_city', model.city_address);

            return this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_PAY_METHOD,
                { search: params })
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                });
        }
    }
```

I think part of my problem is that I am getting the keys from the object inside the constructor. So I think I keep trying to make this work but the only way it will update the keys is when the component refreshes so the constructor will run again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you're assigning data to pMethodsData?

Comment: I can see two ways to deal with this issue. Suggestion one, you return the fresh new created data in your response and push it in the `PaymentMethodKeys` array. Second, you return new PaymentMethodKeys array with fresh data. (or 3, router.navigate() to reconstruct the component ?)

Comment: Of course, I don't know how far along you are with your project, or how committed you are to your API, but if you're really interested in rendering database changes to your view in real time and leveraging the full power of observables you should look into [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and [AngularFire 2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). If you were using Firebase's real-time database, you could simply subscribe to the paymentMethods node and any time it changed, it would immediately render in the client's view--in all clients' views with no need to make any other calls.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that I will read about it right now. I keep having problems like this. Since I started using NG2. Updating components with changes like this has been my only real issue to understand.

Comment: The reason for this is probably that you are using observables in a way that you might typically use promises or callbacks. Observables can be streams that constantly emit updated items to their observers, which you can render in real time, but http responses are one-shot deals. Rendering data from http responses simply does not take full advantage of the tech you have at your disposal with Angular 2 and observables.

Comment: The use of observabels does represent somewhat of a paradigm shift that can prove difficult to grasp, especially at first, but there are few very skilled users who monitor the AngularFire2 tag closely and will help you along if you should choose to go this direction. I wouldn't consider myself very knowledgeable, but I monitor the tag closely and could certainly help you with basic issues and common pitfalls.

Comment: J. would you minding show me an example of how to update a view using an observable? Basically if anytime there is a response the I can subscribe to it for the view to update?

Comment: For an observable that emits more than one item you simply subscribe to it. `myObservable.subscribe(data => this.observer = data)`. And in your view you'd simply interpolate the data. `{{observer.property}}`. Now everytime one of `myObservable`'s properties changes it renders immediately in the view. It's important to note, however, that your http responses won't behave this way, because they depend on the request for updated items. Open chat with me if you'd like to delve into this a bit more.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to create an observable that subscribes to your http responses and to interpolate that in your view. As @mickdev said you'd still need to make at least two requests to get the updated values into the stream, though.

Comment: I am sorry I stepped away for a minute. Yes if you have time and your still around I would appreciate if we could chat for a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137574/discussion-between-j-adam-connor-and-wuno).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discussed Subjects, but that's not necessary. It's sufficient to render the observable in the view and simply pass it new data each time you update your database.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

private paymentMethods: Observable<any>;

private getPaymentMethods() { 
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(); 
    params.set('api_key', this.apiKeyData); 
    params.set('email', this.auth.user.email); 
    this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_ALL_PAYMENT_METHODS, 
    { search: params }) 
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()) 
    .take(1) //Takes the first observable and unsubscribes
    .subscribe(res => this.paymentMethods = res.payment_profiles)
}

saveCreditCard(model: Payment, isValid: boolean) {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('api_key', this.apiKeyData);
    params.set('email', model.email);

    return this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_PAY_METHOD,{ search: params }) 
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .take(1)
    .subscribe((res) => {
        //Maybe make sure status is 200. 
        console.log(res); 
        this.getPaymentMethods(); 
    });
}

ngOnInit() { 
    this.getPaymentMethods()
}
```

Note that since we are subscribing to the results of `getPaymentMethods()` within the function, it's not necessary for it to return anything and, hence, not necessary for us to assign the returned Observable to `paymentMethods` within `ngOnInit()`. Whenever `getPaymentMethods()` is called (e.g., on the initial load and when `saveCreditCard()` is called) `paymentMethods` subscribes to the first response emitted and then unsubscribes with the [`take` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html).

And in your view you'll notice we aren't using the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) anymore. Remember that the async pipe subscribes and unsubscribes. We are doing that manually, so there's no need for that.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of paymentMethods">
    {{item.card_no}}
</div>
```

Let me know how this works out.

Comment: In the solution you have this, this.pmntMethodsSub  I am not understanding what that is supposed to be. Is it just any variable I want to declare there or what?